# What happens if CRC divisor is corrupted during transmission?

Tags: crc

We use CRC for error detection in Data during transmission.In CRC we divide Data by Divisor to check whether the data has error or not. But what happens in case the Divisor gets corrupted during transmission? how do we make sure that it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

The CRC polynomial is not transmitted. It is agreed to ahead of time when the protocol is defined, so both the transmit and the receive side already know the polynomial.